# What's the non-trivial root of $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n x^{2^k}\right)^n$?

Tags: limits, roots

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n x^{2^k}\right)^n=0
$$
always seems to have two real solutions. One trivial $x_0=0$ and another around $x_1=-0.65862...$ (see [W|A @ $n=13$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e7b214ha8rd)). Where does this value converge to?

Neither Wolfram nor ISC+ give a good hint about that...

Comment: In other words, $\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty x^{2^n}$.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė no $\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2^k}\right)^\infty=0$

Comment: Unless I have miscalculated, it seems to me that any number of solutions for $x$ exist such that the given limit goes to $0$...  In particular, many values of $x\in\left[-\frac 12,\frac 12\right]$ will have a sum convergence to a value smaller than $1$, which makes the limit converge to $0$.

Comment: Was the exponent maybe intended to be $\frac1n$? With the exponent $n$, every $x$ such that $-1 < \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^{2^k} < 1$ would produce a $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought it will converge to a certain value, but numerical examples might be misleading...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a known closed form for the zero.  The function $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^{2^k}$ was studied by Mahler in his paper *On a special function*, Journal of Number Theory, Vol. 12, Issue 1, Feb. 1980, pp. 20–26 ([PDF link](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0022314X80900694/1-s2.0-0022314X80900694-main.pdf?_tid=3e3caca0-7055-4890-82ce-b8539fed7648&acdnat=1521786829_be927eaffab099c96d98fba454b86da7)) and he studied the zeros of its partial sums in the paper *On the zeros of a special sequence of polynomials*, Mathematics of Computation , Vol. 39, No. 159, Jul. 1982, pp. 207-212 ([PDF link](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1982-39-159/S0025-5718-1982-0658225-3/S0025-5718-1982-0658225-3.pdf)).

You can be sure that there are exactly two real zeros since

- $f''(x) > 0$ (at most two roots),
- $f(0) = 0$ (found one),
- $f'(0) > 0$ (changes sign here),
- $f(x) \to +\infty$ as $x \to -1^-$ (must change sign again).

Answer (score 4):

There is no one "nontrivial" root. For any sufficiently small (in absolute value) $x$ we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^n x^{2^k}<\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x|^k=\frac{|x|}{1-|x|}<1$$
and since this bound is uniform in $n$, we see that the limit of the $n$th powers goes to $0$.

Comment: hmm, ok. What if I remove the exponent outside the bracket?