# Number of ways, powers of $2$ sum up specific values

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Given the set $B=\{2^0,2^1, 2^2,...2^{n-1} \}$. Now you pick $n$ elements of $B$ with repetitions and sum the picked elements, *e.g.*

- picking every element once this sums up to $s_{1,1,...,1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k= 2^{n}-1$.
- Another *example* would be picking $n$ times the $k$th element resulting in $s_{0,...n,...,0}=n2^k$.

I want to count the number of occurrences of all possible sums I can construct in this way, by using generating functions but I can't figure out how this works in this case.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: One other question: do you want the number of different sums that are possible, or do you also want the number of different ways in which each of those sums can be obtained?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott the latter...

Comment: Do you expect this to have a nice answer?  I can write down a generating function (as I'm sure you're aware as it's exactly the polynomial in your other most recent question), but it doesn't seem to have a simple form that facilitates computing the numbers you want.

Comment: @universalset thanks for pointing out that I was on the right way. I posted an answer and would be glad if you could have a look...

Comment: @BrianM.Scott your first (now deleted) comment should have pointed my to the right direction. I posted an answer and would be glad if you could have a look...

Comment: @draks...: Looks okay to me, though I’m not sure how useful it is in practice.

Comment: @draks... Same comment as (the other) Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There  is  a nice  computation here  that  uses the  **Polya  Enumeration
Theorem** to  treat the  case when order  is not important,  i.e. when
each multiset  of choices only  contributes once. Applying PET  we get
the species equation
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} \mathcal{U}^{2^q}\right).$$

This immediately gives the ordinary generating function
$$F(u) = Z(S_n)\left(\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} u^{2^q}\right)$$
where  $Z(S_n)$ is  the cycle  index of  the symmetric  group  and the
second pair of parenthesis denote cycle index substitution.

Digress for  a moment to  consider the labelled  species $\mathcal{Q}$
given by the specification
$$\mathcal{Q} =
\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{A}_1 \mathfrak{C}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{A}_2 \mathfrak{C}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{A}_3 \mathfrak{C}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots).$$
This corresponds to the generating function 
$$Q(z) =
\exp\left(a_1 z + 
a_2 \frac{z^2}{2} + a_3 \frac{z^3}{3} + \cdots\right).$$

We then  have by inspection the result  that $Q(z)$ is the  OGF of the
cycle index of the symmetric group:
$$Z(S_n) = [z^n] Q(z).$$

Returning to $F(u)$ we get
$$F(u) = [z^n] \exp
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{z^k}{k} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} u^{k2^q} \right).$$

We will  not pick up any large  cycles of length $m$  greater than $n$
from  the species  since  the  term $z^m/m$  will  prevent these  from
appearing in $[z^n] Q(z).$

Now to conclude note that we are only interested in $F(1)$ which gives
the total  number of different  sums that appear and  disregards their
value. Observe that
$$\left.\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} u^{k2^q}\right|_{u=1} = n$$ so that
$$F(1) = [z^n] \exp\left(n \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{z^k}{k}\right)
= [z^n] \exp\left(n \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
= [z^n] \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^n \\=
{n+n-1\choose n-1} = {2n-1\choose n}.$$

We see that  the removal of the dependence on the  actual value of the
sum has  converted the problem  into an application  of stars-and-bars
where  the value  $p$ at  position $k$  indicates that  $p$  copies of
element at position $k$ in the source vector were chosen.

Of course we have the generating functions. E.g. for $n=3$ we get
$${u}^{12}+{u}^{10}+{u}^{9}+{u}^{8}+{u}^{7}+2\,{u}^{6}+{u}^{5}+{
z}^{4}+{u}^{3}$$
and for $n=5$ we have
$${u}^{80}+{u}^{72}+{u}^{68}+{u}^{66}+{u}^{65}+{u}^{64}+{u}^{60}
+{u}^{58}+{u}^{57}+2\,{u}^{56}+{u}^{54}+{u}^{53}\\+2\,{u}^{52}+{
z}^{51}+2\,{u}^{50}+{u}^{49}+2\,{u}^{48}+{u}^{46}+{u}^{45}+3\,
{u}^{44}+{u}^{43}+3\,{u}^{42}+2\,{u}^{41}\\+3\,{u}^{40}+{u}^{39}
+3\,{u}^{38}+2\,{u}^{37}+4\,{u}^{36}+2\,{u}^{35}+3\,{u}^{34}+2
\,{u}^{33}+3\,{u}^{32}+{u}^{31}+4\,{u}^{30}\\+3\,{u}^{29}+4\,{u}
^{28}+3\,{u}^{27}+4\,{u}^{26}+2\,{u}^{25}+4\,{u}^{24}+3\,{u}^{
23}+4\,{u}^{22}+3\,{u}^{21}+4\,{u}^{20}\\+2\,{u}^{19}+3\,{u}^{18
}+2\,{u}^{17}+3\,{u}^{16}+3\,{u}^{15}+3\,{u}^{14}+2\,{u}^{13}+
3\,{u}^{12}+2\,{u}^{11}+2\,{u}^{10}\\+2\,{u}^{9}+2\,{u}^{8}+{u}^
{7}+{u}^{6}+{u}^{5}.$$
The reader may want to verify some of these. E.g. the three multisets for the sum $15$ are $1+1+1+4+8, 1+2+2+2+8$ and $1+2+4+4+4.$

Comment: Could you explain the fractured symbols?

Comment: Wikipedia has this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_combinatorics). The operator $\mathfrak{M}$ represents unlabelled multisets, $\mathfrak{P}$ represents labelled / unlabelled sets and $\mathfrak{C}$ represents oriented labelled / unlabelled cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Take n=4 as an example. Look at the integer partitions of k in n parts of size at most n, with k= n to n^2. This produces all Binomial(2n-1,n-1) sets of exponents k you mentioned:
1111, 1112, 1113, 1122, 1114, 1123, 1222, 1124, 1133, 1223, 2222, 
1134, 1224, 1233, 2223, 1144, 1234, 2224, 1333, 2233, 1244, 1334, 
2234, 2333, 1344, 2244, 2334, 3333, 1444, 2344, 3334, 2444, 3344, 
3444, 4444
Now, as an 'encoding' step, write '1233' as x1*x2*x3*x3 and sum over all;
you get Sum(all partitions p of n;  m(p,n) )
with m(p,n) the monomial symmetric polynomial in n variables.
And that's just the Schur polynomial of single-part-partition {n} in n variables.
You did say '.. any help..'

Comment: Somehow I miss for example $1121$ in your set...

Comment: @draks: I took it that 1121 and 1112 are equivalent since you pick them from an (orderless) set B. Picking 'm with repetitions should not imply that order matters, so why not order them?

Comment: Gotta think about that, thx for your time...

Answer (score 1):

As universalset points out in the comment above, I was already quite close with [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/603475/19341). The correlation in time was not by chance. So here my result:

$$
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{2^k}\right)^{n}
$$
counts what I was looking for. To give an example, let $n=5$:
$$
\color{green}{x^{80}}+5 x^{72}+5 x^{68}+5 x^{66}+5 x^{65}+10 x^{64}+20 x^{60}+20 x^{58}+20 x^{57}+20 x^{56}+20 x^{54}+20 x^{53}+40 x^{52}+20 x^{51}+40 x^{50}+30 x^{49}+35 x^{48}+60 x^{46}+60 x^{45}+60 x^{44}+60 x^{43}+80 x^{42}+50 x^{41}+61 x^{40}+60 x^{39}+100 x^{38}+90 x^{37}+85 x^{36}+70 x^{35}+95 x^{34}+65 x^{33}+75 x^{32}+\color{red}{120 x^{31}}+120 x^{30}+100 x^{29}+110 x^{28}+100 x^{27}+90 x^{26}+90 x^{25}+100 x^{24}+100 x^{23}+90 x^{22}+70 x^{21}+66 x^{20}+70 x^{19}+55 x^{18}+65 x^{17}+75 x^{16}+60 x^{15}+50 x^{14}+50 x^{13}+40 x^{12}+30 x^{11}+31 x^{10}+25 x^{9}+15 x^{8}+10 x^{7}+5 x^{6}+x^{5}
$$
Here you see $5!$ occurrences of $31=2^5-1$ and one of $80=5\cdot 16$.